# SSRS Data Driven Subscription Data Source Credentials Configuration

Tags: reporting-services, datasource, ssrs-2012, subscription, ssrs-2019

I am creating a data driven subscription and that requires you to stored credentials. However, they want want a link to the report embedded in the email. If the user clicks the link then stored credentials will be what is authenticated and not the actual user.

They would like the user to be prompted for authentication when they manually execute the report. Here are a couple of things I was considering:

1. I think I can accomplish this by creating a copy of the report that uses a different data source configured to prompt the user for credentials and use the URL to this report to include in the data driven subscription.
2. I don't think I can do this, in sql update the Credential Retrieval to go from Using the Following Credentials to Prompt the User for Credentials.  However, if you switch it back to use the setting Using the Following Credentials, then I will need to reapply the username and password. Not quite for sure how to do that programmatically.

Does anybody else have an idea on how to handle this?

Comment: How about have 2 version of the report.. one with stored credentials and one without and then embed the link manually somehow in the subscription but point it to the one without the credentials stored.. makes sense?

Comment: Yes. That is similar to my option 1. I have 2 versions of the report with 2 versions of the same data source. One that prompts the user for credentials and the other that has the stored credentials. The data driven subscription would use the report that has the data source with saved credentials and the I include a link to the report that prompts the user for the password. I just didn't know if there was some other way to handle it.